# Score document by array aggregation

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I want to score a document in mongodb based on the elements in the document.
Here is a sample doucment:

```
{
  _id: 5c1257cd37567213449066ce,
  elements: [
   {element: 'abc'},
   {element: 'def'},
   {element: 'ghi'},
  ]
}
```

and the following array has score +5:

```
var plus = ['abc'];
```

and the following array has score -1;

```
var minus = ['def', 'ghi']
```

and I want to get this output

```
{
  _id: 5c1257cd37567213449066ce,
  score: 3
}
```

Comment: Could you  clarify your question.

Comment: @AnthonyWinzlet I want to get documents from database and add a score field to them. That field is calculated based on the elements field

Comment: I can see the `score` is 3 because there are 3 elements inside the `elements` array?

Comment: No, it has 3 points because it has element `abc` with 5 points and has elements `def` and `ghi` with -1 points each. So the total is 5 - 1 - 1 = 3 points

Comment: How do we calculate that points `5 - 1 - 1 = 3`???

Comment: If the elements are in `plus` array they have +5 points and if they are in `minus` array have -1 points

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use below [**`aggregation`**](https://mongoplayground.net/p/RqL42TEGkru)

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "plus": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$elements",
        "as": "s",
        "in": {
          "elements": "$$s.elements",
          "score": { "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$$s.element", ["abc"]] }, 5, 0] }
        }
      }
    },
    "minus": {
      "$map": {
        "input": "$elements",
        "as": "s",
        "in": {
          "elements": "$$s.elements",
          "score": { "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$$s.element", ["def", "ghi"]] }, 1, 0] }
        }
      }
    }
  }},
  { "$project": {
    "score": { "$subtract": [{ "$sum": "$plus.score" }, { "$sum": "$minus.score" }] }
  }}
])
```

If you want to do with a single `$project` stage

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$project": {
    "score": {
      "$subtract": [
        { "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$elements",
            "in": { "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$$this.element", ["abc"]] }, 5, 0] }
          }
        }},
        { "$sum": {
          "$map": {
            "input": "$elements",
            "in": { "$cond": [{ "$in": ["$$this.element", ["def", "ghi"]] }, 1, 0] }
          }
        }}
      ]
    }
  }}
])
```

Comment: How can I cast each element to `ObjectID` in `$map`?

Comment: It's not daunting. Simply do this `mongoose.Types.ObjectId("$$this.element")`

Answer (score 0):

You can just iterate over your elements and sum up the individual values.

- I used `reduce` here for the iteration.
- `{element}` for destructing the array element to only its `element` value.
- `.includes()` to check if the arrays contain the element.

```js
const o = {
  _id: '5c1257cd37567213449066ce',
  elements: [{
      element: 'abc'
    },
    {
      element: 'def'
    },
    {
      element: 'ghi'
    },
  ]
};

const plus = ['abc'];

const minus = ['def', 'ghi']

function score(arr) {
  return arr.reduce((s, {
    element
  }) => {
    if (plus.includes(element)) return s + 5;
    if (minus.includes(element)) return s - 1;
    return s;
  }, 0);
}

o.score = score(o.elements);
console.log(o);
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I want to use mongoose aggregate